# Is there a way to link 2 the same email across multiple users

Tags: gmail-api

We are looking for a way to determine if an email in different users gmail is the same email.  For example Person A sends an email to Person B and C who are in the same Google Apps instance.

When retrieving the email with the gmail API the Id and ThreadId are different for the email in both user B and C accounts.  Is there some common identifier or is a case of using something like "Sender" + "Recipients" + "Time Sent" as the relating key?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if/how this is related to Gmail API, but why not use the Message-Id header? (In conjunction with Date header and possibly From if you want to be sure/paranoid.  Note that many assumptions may be broken if a mailing-list is part of the delivery to the recipients.)